# ControlSend function is not working in AutoIt (Calling in python)

Tags: python, autoit

> In my python script i'm converting Autoit script into python script. All the default function in Autoit script is working fine except ControlSend function.Please refer my code below and guide me whats wrong in the script.

```
    Auto = Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
    Auto.Run("calc.exe")
    time.sleep(1)
    Auto.Send("AZERTYUIOP = ")
    hwnd=Auto.WinGetHandle("[TITLE:Calculator; CLASS:CalcFrame]")
    time.sleep(1)
    titreFenetre = 'Calculatrice'
    Auto.WinActivate(titreFenetre , '')
    time.sleep(1)
    Auto.ControlSend(hwnd, "", hwnd, "12345") #ControlSend is not working
    Auto.Send("12345") #Send function is working
```

> In above script i'm doing in python scripter , Auto.ControlSend(hwnd, "", hwnd, "12345") is not working (If i call ControlSend function in autoit it is working). Is there any way available to convert Autoit script to python. Guide me

Answer (score 0):

> After long struggle , i found a solution . The idea is to run the Autoit script in python script. I used below lines to execute Autoit script directly in python script.

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\\test.au3")
```